# Celery in Amazon Server

Tags: python, celery

I have two nodes (two computers are already connected) in the server and every node has 4 cores, how can I cluster these two computers using celery + RabbitMQ, when I start celeryd, it shows that:

```
 -------------- celery@ip-10-77-137-41 v3.0.19 (Chiastic Slide)
 ---- **** ----- 
 --- * ***  * -- Linux-3.2.0-36-virtual-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
 -- * - **** --- 
 - ** ---------- [config]
 - ** ---------- .> broker:      amqp://celeryuser@localhost:5672/celeryvhost
 - ** ---------- .> app:         default:0x29ecf90 (.default.Loader)
 - ** ---------- .> concurrency: 2 (processes)
 - *** --- * --- .> events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)
 -- ******* ---- 
 --- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery:      exchange:celery(direct) binding:celery
```

Can I just set concurrency as 8 to using these two nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each server launch a celery worker with concurrency level 4

```
celery worker --concurrency=4
```